# Naming rules for Android resources

Tags: android, resources, naming

where can I find the naming rules for Android resources? I found out thanks to compilation errors that I must use characters within [a-z0-9._], but I also have an error with an image named 401.png. When using it in my layout using

```
@drawable/401
```

I get the following compilation error:

```
invalid VariableDeclaratorId
```

I can't find these rules in the doc, and I'd like to know all of them before naming my files.

Thanks

Comment: just change name to e401.png ... remember that id become static fields in R(resources) class so i think naming rules are the same as fields rules in java

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The rules are the same as for [Java identifiers](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.8) since each resource must have a corresponding ID field generated in the R.java file.

Answer (score 6):

Worth noting that: "File-based resource names must contain only lowercase a-z, 0-9, or underscore" characters. (quoted from compile error code).

Answer (score 2):

The number is not allowed as first char of resource also not any capital letter

Comment: Capital letter is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Your convention is correct, except that you can't start your file names with a number.

Answer (score 0):

Naming rules for resources are the same as for the variables, except the case-sensitivity. In your case, problem is the first character is number.

Answer (score 0):

This is Java rule, not Android-only rule. Name each element with a starting letter, and you'll be right.