# No resource found that matches the given name (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've been trying to figure this one out for hours and I have to finally resort to asking here. I added 6 pictures to my app, and have them set up in a Table Layout. When I go to run my app, it says:

**No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value @drawable/picture_name)**

Then after this error happens, my **R** file becomes corrupted. The first time this happened, I tried everything to fix it but assumed I had just messed something up. So I re-created the app from scratch, and the same exact thing happened!

There are no capitals in my file names. I have made sure all the images are png files. I have made sure they're in the right folder. I am really at a loss here.

I would post code but I'm not sure what's worth posting. Any help on this would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: delete the files in the bin and clean rebuild...

Comment: What are the file names and what folder are they in?

Comment: post the names of the files, the XML file, the directory structure and the exact error message. A corrupt R file is most likely a bad filename, but it might not be obvious (for example, you mentioned capitals but there are other restrictions since they are java identifiers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949395/naming-rules-for-android-resources)

Answer (score 0):

Please check all the layout file, check the file-name inside drawable & check weather any error on AndroidManifest.xml, if any error on those files also your Resource(R) will not generate.