# Why images in drawable folder are not showing in my Android compilation of Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, image, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I try to compile my Xamarin.Forms app and the images in the drawable folder can´t be loaded... The screen shows all the elements except images or icons.
I also get the error that says "obj/bin/debug/packaged_resources" doesn´t exist... It seems that this file is not being generated. I´m temporally avoiding this error by copy-pasting this file from another version of the app in my version control, but like I said before, images are not showing.
I have also checked the correct name of the image files to be compatible.

I have tried lots of purposes in Xamarin forums and cannot solve the problem. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: There're so many possibilities may cause your failure at showing an image. Without any code or image of your drawable folder etc...we can only guess, for the first thing, have you checked your resources' names? Do you have some  invalid characters like "-" in your resource's name? Please check this case: [Naming rules for Android resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949395/naming-rules-for-android-resources).

Comment: I have had this problem since I upgraded to VS 2017.  VS 2017 doesn't display errors when generating the resource file.  I normally open the solution back in VS 2015 and it will give me the correct error.

Comment: please share some code where you are trying to display images

Comment: try deleting your bin and obj folder and doing a clean build

Comment: Thank you all for the help... I have checked my resource names: all of them are correct now without capital letters or numbers and no "-" charachters...   I´m trying to display images by xaml like this: <Image Source="name.png">   I have also tryed deleting my bin and obj folder and still getting the same error...

Comment: The images are showing fine in the UWP and the iOS version.

Comment: @Saizant, not sure what happened, have you tried embedded resource?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT I´m trying with "Build action: Android resource" property in each image in drawable folder... It has to work like this, but is frustrating...

Answer (score 0):

Please add the file with the help of "Add file" context not copying directly or dragging in to the resource folder..

Also rebuild the project after adding those image files..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. If you exclude image in one of the drawable folder and then include then it become visible in preview as well.