# Images in drawable-v24 resource folder not showing up in image button?

Tags: android, android-studio, naming-conventions

I have various icons I am trying to use for some buttons. These icons exist in a drawable-v24 resource folder. When I try to set the "android:src="drawable-icon" to my resource, the image never shows up. Does it make a difference that the icon exists in "drawable-v24", but my resource calls the "drawable" folder? I'm sorry, I'm really not sure what to ask here. I'm very novice when it comes to this.

My XML code:

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/history_button"
        android:layout_width="74dp"
        android:layout_height="81dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/horizontal_border"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/vertical_border"
        android:src="@drawable/icons8-time-machine-24" />
```

The button shows up as a plain gray button, without the black "time-machine" icon that should be showing up.

Comment: What's the version of the SDK you are building with?  What about the capabilities of the device you are running your app on?  Have you tried moving the drawable file to the "drawable" folder?

Comment: file name issue, rename the icon file name and replace all the ``hyphens`` with ``underscores``

``icons8-time-machine-24`` to ``icons8_time_machine_24``

Comment: @OMiShah That's it! I can't believe I struggled for all those hours with this.

Comment: ‍♂️ I hope I helped you 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is having issues due to the naming of your drawable file namely the fact that you are using dashes instead of the "_" underscore sign usually employed. you can just name the drawable time_machine. let me know if this is the case.

look at this answer for reference: [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34970898/10637400)

Comment: I have put my resources in the "drawable file" themselves but they still fail to show up. I'm not sure what else I could be doing wrong.

Comment: I have hunch the issue is the name of your drawable. try replacing the dashes with underscores i.e.name your file something like "time_machine_icon" instead of "icons8-time-machine-24" look ath this https://stackoverflow.com/a/34970898/10637400 i will write this in the answer so you can confirm if it is right

Comment: great, happy to have helped. you can mark the answer as correct (check mark next to the question). ill just edit it ;)

Comment: @JimmyBlundell you should click the check mark to indicate this is the right answer (or alternatively write the answer yourself and mark it). that way people know your issue is resolved. and no more people will have to read it in order help resolve a resolved issue.