# I can't seem to get the text to update after the click event

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

sorry for the title, wasn't really sure what to write. I am trying to write a simple program where the user can hit an increment button or decrement button and the number displayed changes accordingly. However, I am having two problems. 1) I cannot seem to get the view(? little confused on this) to update so the number changes on the click event 2) visual studio is telling me I don't have "textView1" in my resources...

Any help/enlightenment is appreciated

XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:text="+"
    android:textSize="100sp"
    android:layout_width="200sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="325px"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/button1" />
<TextView
    android:text="0"
    android:textSize="100sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView1" />
<Button
    android:text="-"
    android:textSize="100sp"
    android:layout_width="200sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="325px"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/button2" />
```

Main code:

```
   namespace WhyDoesThisNotWork
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        //View v;
        Button btnIncrement;
        Button btnDecrement;
        int lifeTotal = 0;

        TextView textView1;


        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout1);

            btnIncrement = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
            this.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1).Click += this.Increment;

            btnDecrement = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button2);
            this.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button2).Click += this.Decrement;

            textView1 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
            textView1.Text = lifeTotal.ToString();

        }

        public void Increment(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lifeTotal++;

        }

        public void Decrement(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lifeTotal--;
        }

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use exclusively lower case letters and _ in the names of your resource xml files ;)
name it text_view_1 for instance

look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34970898/10637400) related question. this has happened to me as well

in order to have the text uppdate ttry

```
 public void Increment(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lifeTotal++;
        textView1.Text = lifeTotal.ToString();
    }

    public void Decrement(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lifeTotal--;
        textView1.Text = lifeTotal.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: What about the text not updating?

Comment: once the click is made on the button you are only updating the counter i.e. lifeTotal you need to add some code to the Increment and Decrement methods that updates the text in textView1. I dont know what that is in Xamarin but probably something like textView1.Text = lifeTotal.ToString(); <--- put this in the methods

Answer (score 0):

**It is always happen to me but I don't know the exact solution so I follow these steps :**

> 1- Try to run your application ,some times it is working with this
>   kind of error.
>
> 2- Try to "Clean Solution" then "Build Solution" from Build tab then
>   look at Error List maybe you will see another errors that cause this
>   error.
>
> 3- Change the XML file name then do step (2).
>
> 4- If you insert this XML file "or activity file" directly to your project then delete it
>   and make it manually ,just add a layout to your project then copy the
>   code to the new file then do step (2), this step .
>
> 5- Close Visual Studio and go to your project folder and rename "bin"
>   and "obj" folders then open your project and do step (2).
>
> 6- Update Visual Studio and try the steps again.

**Use this code to call click function:**

```
myButton.Click += delegate
            {
                //your code here                
            };
```